# Flutter-Dart List-Map get item number or text where i clicked?

Tags: list, flutter, dictionary, dart

I wanna get a String or Map Number int if I clicked on List. I wanna forward to another Function. Like this,

I got a List,

```
List <String> konulistesi = <String> ["Max","Adam","Anna","Sophie","Alex",]
```

And if I click on the List example Adam, then it will print to number like : 1, or for Sophie print:  3,

```
body: SafeArea(
              child:
              ListView.separated(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                itemCount: konuListesi.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return Container(
                    height: 50,
                    color: Colors.green,
                    child: InkWell(child:
                    Center(child:


                    Text(konuListesi[index],style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black,fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,fontSize: 18),),),
                    onTap: ()=> {

                   
                   
           
                 print("Number of the Position or direkt Item"),

                      
                    }),

                  );
                },

                separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => const Divider(),


              ),
          ),
```

Comment: print(index); index is defined up there

Answer (score 0):

You should not use the [arrow function](https://medium.com/run-dart/dart-dartlang-introduction-functions-and-fat-arrow-expression-d9ce8e22c2da) for the onTap method of the InkWell widget. `print(index)` will give you the index of the array. `print(index + 1)` will give you the countable index of the array. The index of an array starts with 0 in Dart.

And, `print(konuListesi[index])` will give you the selected item:

```
     onTap: () {
                                            
               print("Number of the Position or direkt Item");
               print(index);
               print(konuListesi[index]);
                  
                }),
```